# What exactly makes the difference between a "React function" in contrast to a "regular Javascript function"?

Tags: reactjs

The react docs boldly state that hooks shall only be called inside **"React functions"**:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions

"Don’t call Hooks from **regular JavaScript** functions."

That raises the question what *precisely* distinguishes a React function from a regular js function. Is it the return of a JSX Element? How about those functions:

```
function F1() { return <div>hello</div> } // certainly can use hooks 

function F2() { return F1() }   // can use hooks? is a react function? is a regular js function?
function F2() { return <F1 /> } // makes no difference, right?

function F3(s) { return <div>{s}</div> } // is a react function because uses jsx?  

function F4() { return F3("bugs bunny") }

function F5({s}) { return <div>{s}</div> }
```

They all return a JSX Element. But I am not sure that f2 or f4 really are React functions and participate in the hook attachment. The way we pass arguments should only not matter. So the question: What exactly makes the difference?

(I know how JSX, hyperscript work, no need to explain those basics. I just did not look into the internals of the hook system.)

Answer (score 2):

Whether the function is a component or not comes down to how you will use the function. Do you plan to render it as a JSX element, eg: `<f1 />`? If so, it's a react component and it can use hooks (though you will need to rename it to uppercase, as in `<F1 />`). During the render process, react will call your function, but only after it has set up the appropriate internal state so that the hooks can work correctly.

On the other hand, if you plan to call it directly (eg, `f1()`), you can't set up react's internal state for it, and react won't know you're calling the function so it can't do the setup for you. Thus, the only way you can get away with calling hooks in this kind of function is if you exclusively call this function while another component is rendering. This is called a "custom hook". They're a very useful tool for reusing code, but you should use the naming convention of starting with `use`, so that the programmer and the lint tools know to enforce the rules of hooks.

Comment: Changed the casing to match JSX requirements, good point. Lets consider all those functions to serve the purpose of rendering: Can F2 and F4 use hooks? Quite certainly yes. So without restating why the react team believes hooks are great: what precisely makes the difference between a "react function" and a "regular" function? - this is not clearly answered. What exactly does the hook system need? As unclear as the react docs are, I believe your point about the function context, the function call environment, is correct. Then the docs are bad or even wrong.

Comment: @citykid "React functions" are components. The docs seem correct, if not completely clear.

Comment: I see it the same way. They mean component functions that are directly attached to the fiber. Since the hook mechanism is so brittle in contrast to simple class components, the docs are alike and they try to define clear the strong limits where hooks do not get the developer into much trouble and they reach the ice while doing so.

Answer (score 1):

**You get to decide whether a function is a React function, a custom function, or a regular function, which defines who can call it from where.** If F1 is a React function (functional component) you can call it as `<F1 />` but should not call it as `F1()`; if F1 is a regular function you can call it as `F1()` but should not call it as `<F1 />`. The naming convention (F1, f1, or useF1) would help you distinguish which type of function you intend, which helps you and the linter hold to those rules; things might work if you break the rules, but they also might fail in difficult-to-debug ways.

- **React function** (functional component): Call from `createElement` or JSX. Can call hooks according to the rules and should return `createElement` or JSX expressions. Named with upper camel case (`Foo`) by convention.
- **Custom hook**: Call from functional components or other custom hooks. Can call hooks according to the rules; can return anything. Named with lower camel case starting with "use" (`useFoo`) by convention.
- **Regular function**: Call from anywhere. Shouldn't call hooks; can return anything. Named with lower camel case (`foo`) as usual.

---

In addition to Nicholas Tower's answer, you should observe that `<F1 />` and `F1()` are not identical. From the ["JSX Represents Objects" header of React's Main Concepts / Introducing JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects):

> Babel compiles JSX down to `React.createElement()` calls.
>
> These two examples are identical:
>
> ```
> const element = (
>   <h1 className="greeting">
>     Hello, world!
>   </h1>
> );
> ```
>
> ```js
> const element = React.createElement(
>   'h1',
>   {className: 'greeting'},
>   'Hello, world!'
> );
> ```

Specifically, this example:

```
function F1() {
  return <F1>hello</F1>;
}

function F2() {
}
```

compiles to [this JS](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.21&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAMQIwAoCUiDeAoRRAJwFMoQikAeNAPgAsSAbJuKgejoG48BfPPKEiwEKAExZcfIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.18.13&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D):

```js
"use strict";

function F1() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(F1, null, "hello");
}

function F2() {}
```

**F1 doesn't call F2, F1 passes F2 to `React.createElement()`.** Consequently, `createElement` gets to call F2 *exactly and only* when it is ready to do so, allowing it to create a fresh internal state (i.e. history of hook calls). So when you [define F2 like this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation):

```
// React function, returns JSX
function F2() {
  useState('Mary')           // 1. Initialize the name state variable with 'Mary'
  useEffect(persistForm)     // 2. Add an effect for persisting the form
  useState('Poppins')        // 3. Initialize the surname state variable with 'Poppins'
  useEffect(updateTitle)     // 4. Add an effect for updating the title
  useLogin()                 // 5 & 6
}

// Custom hook, can call hooks according to rules, named "use" by convention
function useLogin() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(getDefaultUser());
  const [domain, setDomain] = useState(getDomain());
}

// Normal function, can't call hooks
function getDefaultUser() {
  return "defaultUser";
}
```

...then React can generate a new hook state for that particular component invocation, call F2 itself, and then wind up with an internal state that looks like `[useState, useEffect, useState, useEffect, useState(useLogin:user), useState(useLogin:domain)]`. Because of the rules for hooks barring conditionals and loops, if you've done it right, every invocation of F2 will wind up with exactly those six entries. If you use hooks from a "regular Javascript function" like `getDefaultUser()`, it might work by accident, but it will be harder to understand the usage and hold to the rules.

Thus, you are the one that determines which type of function a function is, all in service of keeping that state predictable.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I will think about all this. First I find the react teams' concepts disturbingly confusing. As for know the simple question - what is a "regular" and what a "react" function - is not answerable, it depends on their intended usage. But the docs say that the linter can distnguish those, which raises the question how does the linter knows what I intend? The question on a FORMAL distinction is still open, but I will digg into your answer more deeply. thx

Comment: `But the docs say that the linter can distnguish those, which raises the question how does the linter knows what I intend?` That part's very easy: it uses naming conventions. Functions that start with an uppercase letter are assumed to be components. Functions that start with `use` are assumed to be custom hooks. All other functions are assumed to not be components, nor custom hooks.

Comment: @citykid But it *is* answerable; usage determines the answer. The more dynamic a language is the more things depend on usage, naming, etc. Less can be determined statically. Linters analyze your source; if a function is used as a component it's clear what the intent is.